# nginx для php настройка

Tags: php, nginx

**Процесс настройки nginx**

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/"my_domain"/html

sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/"my_domain"/html

sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/"my_domain"

sudo vim /var/www/"my_domain"/html/index.html

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome to my_domain!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Success!  The my_domain server block is working!</h1>
    </body>
</html>

sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/"my_domain"

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/my_domain/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name my_domain www.my_domain;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/my_domain /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

...
http {
    ...
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    ...
}
...

sudo nginx -t

nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

"my_domain" = blog.uz

Настройка успешная, но при переходе по **blog.uz** ошибка, сервер не работает. Где есть ошибка ?

Comment: _при переходе по blog.uz ошибка_ - какая ошибка?

Comment: Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site.

We can’t connect to the server at www.blog.uz.

If that address is correct, here are three other things you can try:

    Try again later.
    Check your network connection.
    If you are connected but behind a firewall, check that Firefox has permission to access the Web.

Comment: Все вроде правильно настроил, но когда перехожу не переходит, выдает такую ошибку...

Comment: Не понимаю вообще, не работает.

Comment: Это точно не nginx. Переоткройте браузер

Comment: Когда набераю в адресной строке: http://www.blog.uz или blog.uz или www.blog.uz направляет сюда: https://www.blog.uz но такой адрес не существует.

Comment: Перезапустил браузер, но ошибка существует досихпор.

Comment: Неплохо бы ещё DNS настроить

Comment: Так про DNS не было слов

Comment: Удалил все. Заново попробую. Спасибо всем.

Comment: А браузер по вашему из мирового эфира берёт ip-адреса сайтов?

Comment: Термин DNS мне пока не знаком, я не знаю пока как он работает. Но, скоро узнаю.